# Apply Pandas Apply Lambda to Whole Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I'd like to know how to use the pandas apply function for a whole dataframe. Here is my code:

```
def apply_imputation(df, row):
    return df[df.index == row.donor_index]

df.apply(lambda row : apply_imputation(df, row) if row['imp_flag'] == 1 else row, axis=1)
```

I am trying to pass in rows, and completely replace those rows with rows from a different index (from the row.donor_index). Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Edit3:
Here is a sample of the input dataframe:

```
        lsoa11cd postcode_nospace  ... donor_possible_indexes  donor_index
8119   W01000209          LL208RQ  ...                    NaN          NaN
13707        NaN              NaN  ...                 [8119]       8119.0
```

What I want to do is: for every row that has a value on donor_index, replace that entire row with the row who's indexed is specified in donor_index.

This means that row 13707 should be overwritten by row 8119. Instead, after applying the function above, I get this:

```
                       lsoa11cd  ...                        donor_index
8119                  W01000209  ...                                NaN
13707  (l, s, o, a, 1, 1, c, d)  ...  (d, o, n, o, r, _, i, n, d, e, x)
```

As you can see something has gone wrong with our target row 13707. Can anybody tell me what's happening here?

Comment: can you share a sample of your dataset with your expected output? see [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: @Umar.H I have edited the question now

Comment: can you show moer than a single row? I need to see both indexes in the input dataframe.

Comment: I have edited the question again to make this more clear

Comment: Still no output example ?

Answer (score 0):

`df.apply` function doesn't replace in your dataframe but give you a dataframe back. You should write it back to your dataframe.

```py
def apply_imputation(df, row):
    return df.loc[row.donor_index]

df = df.apply(lambda row : apply_imputation(df, row) if row['imp_flag'] == 1 else row, axis=1)
```

Comment: It doesn't work - I get the problem I mentioned in the question, where each cell is replaced with the column name, e.g. ('c', 'o', 'l') if column name = col